# start Intent with contact as vCard in string

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin, android-contacts

How is possible to start a new contact Intent with vCard stored as a string?
Is possible set a raw vCard instead of URI in some way?
A sort of:

```
intent.setDataAndType(vcardAsString,"text/x-vcard")
```

Comment: what do you want the intent to actually do? display a contact details? if so, that's not possible from a string, the contact must inserted into the contacts DB using ContactsContract api

Comment: Yes, I want to open it in Contacts. I use ContactsContract now, inserting items one by one. Is possible to import whole vCard at once?

Comment: not possible in the API, but the open source contacts app on Android does it, you can copy that code to your project, but it's quite complicated code, adding items one by one would be simpler. the other direction is possible in the API though, exporting a contact to a vcard.

Comment: But NDEF message (with vCard as a string) caught by system is converted to Intent with contact information. So it is converted to ContactsContract API format by Tag dispatch system?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Android's AOSP moved the vcard handling out of the Messaging app to the Contacts app, so it seems it's possible now.

However, it's not purely programmatic, the user would be presented with a UI to select the account in which she wants to store that incoming contact.

To test it out, download [an example vcf file](https://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/john-doe.vcf) to your phone's Downloads folder, then run the following intent:

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -t "text/vcard" -d "file:///sdcard/Download/john-doe.vcf"
```

or in code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Download/john-doe.vcf"));
intent.setType("text/vcard");
startActivity(intent);
```

So in your app, you need to save your string to a file on the SD card, where the Contacts app can read from (not your app's private data folder), and send the intent along with the uri pointing to that file.

Comment: thank you, so it is not possible send vcard as extra directly in Intent?

Comment: doesn't look like it's possible, you can check their code here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/a33aca875ae2135e720385d07d637cf8819c7f8a/src/com/android/contacts/vcard/ImportVCardActivity.java